# XML Array Standards

Tags: arrays, xml, xml-parsing

i have questions about array standards and i couldn't find on web. Maybe you guys can help me?
Normally,

```
<arr><a>1</a><a>2<a/><a>3<a/><arr/>
```

This is an array, and can be represented in json

```
{arr:{a:[1, 2, 3]}}
```

But if there is xml like

```
<arr><a>1</a><b>2<b/><a>3<a/><arr/>
```

Is it allowed by standards? 
Can `b tag` come between an array? Then how it can be validated by xsd files?

There is too many questions if it is allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a hard standard for xml, but having mixture of two tags (a,b) is non-conventional and makes it hard to parse results.  Any good programming standard says to make code easy to parse.  Don't go out of your way to make code difficult.

Comment: I see, then its not guaranteed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what "standards" you are referring to.

As far as XML goes, there are no arrays. And in regards to XSD, the second example can perfectly be modeled, for instance as sequence of `a` or `b` elements (choice).

If you want/need to convert XML to JSON or vice-versa, you may need to adhere to a subset of XML which allows for a round-trip, e.g. use a convention how specific patterns in XML get converted to JSON, or the other way around. There are other issues that need to be taken care of, such as the order of elements (significant) versus the order of properties (insignificant) in a JSON object.

That being said, a possible JSON representation of the second snippet would be:

```
{arr:[{a:1},{b:2},{a:3}]}
```

Comment: I want to know if there is an example lie

Comment: I want to know if there is an example like: <arr><a>1</a><b>2</b><a>3</a><b>4</b></arr> is there two arrays?

Comment: I clicked post button by mistake